# Can we call main() method of the Parent from a subclass in java?

Tags: java

we know that static members are available to their subclasses as well depending on their access modifier.

So i have following classes as:

```
            public class A {

            public static void main(String[] args){
            //.....
            }
            }

            public class B extends A{
            //....
            }
```

So i wanted to know that if run class B. will it run through the main method available for it through inheritance. if not Why?

Comment: Why did you not just try this?

Comment: i tried in eclipse but it is not giving me an open to RUN AS JAVA APPLICATION.

Comment: Did you create it as Java Project?

Comment: Ya. For class A it will give the option to run as java application, but for class B it wont.

Comment: tried with command console it works.

Comment: Good question. At least, I learned something new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you run it, It'll execute parent class' main method.
The static method will'be inherited but can't be overriden.
If you define any static method with same name in subclass it'll only hide the parent method not override it.

Comment: +1 for trying it out. I just made my post based on wrong assumption. Actually, was lazy to try that out. Cheers.