# Finding name of subclass running Main

Tags: java, reflection, subclass, program-entry-point

I want to make a convenient super class that will make an instance of whatever [subclass it is ran from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243920/can-we-call-main-method-of-the-parent-from-a-subclass-in-java), without having to hard-code the name of the sub class. What is the fastest way to do this?

We can assume that the subclasses' constructors will have same signature, e.g. no parameters.

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Main m = new NAME-OF-SUBCLASS();
    }
} 

class MainSub1 extends Main { /*...*/ } 
class MainSub2 extends Main { /*...*/ }
```

So when invoking main from MainSub1 (`$ java MainSub1` from the command line), a MainSub1 object is created, etc.

As I wrote this, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313271/create-subclass-from-superclass-static-main) thread where the accepted answer says it can't be done, but of course it can, somehow, through reflection or something, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'd really recommend it, but there's a dirty trick to it:

```
class Main {
    static Main m;
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        // use m
    }
} 

class MainSub1 extends Main { static { m = new MainSub1(); } } 
class MainSub2 extends Main { static { m = new MainSub2(); } }
```

A serious answer would be to write a separate `main` for each subclass, but let it call a common inherited method that accepts an appropriate instance.

Comment: Problem is, there is no "current instance" in a static method.   So how does this work?

Comment: Oh, I see now. OP wants to reuse the `main` method. Hm. Then there really is no help. Or is there...

Comment: @cHao Rewrote the answer with an admittedly ugly, dirty trick.

Comment: Yeah, that is dirty indeed, but I guess it'll have to work for now :) thanks.